# Query between two tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I got one question for you. I think it's easy to resolve, but I'm very locked on this.

I have two tables, one with products and another one with favorites. Favorites table has 2 fields, `id_user` and `id_product`.

Now, I want to query all the favorites products and show them on my webpage. I think I have to do a `join` on my query, but at the moment I'm really lost.

For example I want to show all the favorites products from the user with `id = 3`, what I should do?

Comment: Can yous hare the table layouts?

Comment: subquery or join. example of subquery: `SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN(SELECT id_product FROM favourites WHERE id_user = 3)`

Answer (score 3):

For future reference , when asking questions on Stack, you need to include all the relevant information. Such as your database layout. We're not mind-readers, here's a guess though.

```
Select * from Favorites junk
Left join Products poop on
poop.id = junk.id_product
Left join Users stuff on
stuff.id = junk.id_user
```

Answer (score 1):

You looking for a query like this with a join.

```
select a.* from favourites as a join products as b on a.id_product= b.id
```

Comment: Maybe this is the solution, but i want to get the product information so, this will be like this, no?

`select b.* from products b join favourites a on a.id_product = b.id`

Comment: Yes this is how your query should be like...So you will get every favourite product based on the product ID..done

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the main query against your "favourites" table and join the products table, so assuming that your id_product field points to the id field in your products table:

```
SELECT fav.*, prod.* FROM favourites fav RIGHT JOIN products prod ON prod.id = fav.id
```

Note that I use RIGHT JOIN here because you want to ensure the right-hand table (in this case favourites) has information to retrieve (otherwise you'll get NULL results if the id_product points to a non existent id). Also note I have given each table an alias (`fav` and `prod` respectively) because this makes the query easier/quicker to write.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an INNER JOIN.

If you follow the example below, you can get the idea. I don't know what you have in your Products table. From your description it looks like you'd join on the User ID.

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
/*
Create a Join on 2 tables to show information from both. The example tables are from the AdventureWorks database:
    Production.Product
    Production.ProductInventory

In this example we'll look to get the Product ID and Name from the Product table and the inventory quantity, shelf, and bin from the     ProductInventory table.
*/

SELECT
/* Precede each column you want to select with the identifier of which table it's coming from */
    prod.ProductID,
    prod.Name,
    inv.Shelf,
    inv.Bin,
    inv.Quantity

/* Select items from the Product Table */
FROM Production.Product AS prod 

/* Use an INNER JOIN to get the items related to the Product table that are in the ProductInventory table based on the ProductID */
INNER JOIN Production.ProductInventory AS inv ON
    prod.ProductID = inv.ProductID
```